# Interpretation maxima %rnum_list

Tags: maxima-software

I don't really understand how to interpret the output of the function `solve()` in Maxima.
For instance, I have to sove this:

```
solve(a1*x1/(a1*x1+a2*x2)-r1*x1/(r1*x1+r2*x2),[x1,x2]);
[[x1=%r1,x2=0],[x1=0,x2=%r2]]
```

Are `%r1` and `%r2` 2 constants ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the docs](http://maxima.sourceforge.net/docs/manual/maxima_20.html#Item_003a-algsys):

> The symbols `%r1`, `%r2`, …, are introduced as needed to represent arbitrary parameters in the solution; these variables are also appended to the list [%rnum_list](http://maxima.sourceforge.net/docs/manual/maxima_20.html#g_t_0025rnum_005flist).